# If "that which intoxicates in large quantities" is haram, does that mean water is haram?

Tags: hadith-interpretation

As there are no direct verses in the Qur'an about smoking, I asked some people about "why is marijuana haram?"  In reply, the following hadith was quoted to me:

> "That which intoxicates in large quantities is prohibited in small quantities." (Abu Dawud, Tirmidhi, Ibn Majah, and others, with a sound chain of narrators)

So my question is, given that if someone drinks excessive of water than he/she risks death due to [water intoxication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_intoxication), does this necessarily mean that water is also prohibited in small amounts?

Obviously this is absurd on the surface, because [water isn't (and probably shouldn't) be haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8579/can-water-be-halal-or-haram), but how can this hadith be reconciled with the fact that water intoxication exists?

Comment: Please ask separate questions for the other questions in your post.

Comment: Multiple questions should be asked as separate questions.  I have taken the liberty of focussing this question to the "water intoxication" one as it's the one covered by the current answer.

Comment: in regards to your question on marijuana, check out this related question which may give you your answer: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7363/is-smoking-marijuana-haraam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get intoxicated from water is VERY RARE. You would have to be a fool to get intoxicated from water. But intoxication from drug is very possible in even small quantities. Water is also a necessity to survive. Anything consume at a ridiculous amount will intoxicant you.

in the quran it says

"O You who believe! Intoxicants and gambling, (dedication of) stones and (divination by) arrows are an abomination of Satan’s handiwork. Avoid (such abominations) that you may prosper. (5:90)"

The verse in the Quran specifically states intoxicants, not something that intoxicates you when you have a ridiculous amount of it.

Comment: Sometimes in sweets, chocolates or ice creams etc they have small amounts of alcohol it’s not possible to get intoxicated of them is it?

Answer (score 4):

The word "moskir" and its derivatives are usually translated as "intoxicants."  But this is not correct and doesn't really explain the actual meaning.

Moskir (or sukara) literally means **being in a state where you don't know what you're saying.** Allah defines it this way in Surah an-Nisa ayah 43.

So basically, moskir is what makes you drunk.

Drinking water in large amounts doesn't make you drunk.

Answer (score 1):

Assalam O Alaikum,
If something kills you before it intoxicates you is not haram. Water will kill you if you drink gallons and gallons of it but it will not intoxicate you. If something intoxicates you in a large quantity (By large quantity we mean a reasonable quantity) is haram in small quantity beer for example if you drink 10 glasses you will become intoxicated (high) therefore a drop of that beer is haram. Kindly watch this video for complete details on Minute Quantities of Alcohol in Our Food? (Ie. Vanilla).
Jazakallaho Khair.

Answer (score 0):

Water intoxication does not make you loose your mind.
The intoxication of any kind that makes you lose your senses is what is prohibited.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on answering the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).